# How can I create a Customer Refund without seeing this error "USER_ERROR You must enter at least one line item for this transaction"?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a Customer Refund from a Return Authorization and Credit Memo. The error message sounds like I don't have any line items even though there is at least 1.

This is the code I'm using to create the Customer Refund:

```
var returnAuth = nlapiLoadRecord("returnauthorization", returnAuthId);

var status = returnAuth.getFieldValue("status");
nlapiLogExecution("debug", "status", status);
if (status != "Pending Refund")
    throw "Status needs to be \"Pending Refund\" in order to create a Credit Memo and Customer Refund.";

var paymentMethod = returnAuth.getFieldValue("custbody_cc_payment_method");

var creditMemo = nlapiTransformRecord("returnauthorization", returnAuthId, "creditmemo");
var creditMemoId = nlapiSubmitRecord(creditMemo);
var creditMemo = nlapiLoadRecord("creditmemo", creditMemoId);
var creditMemoTransId = creditMemo.getFieldValue("tranid");
nlapiLogExecution("debug", "Credit Memo Id", creditMemoId);

// create the Customer Refund record
var customerRefund = nlapiCreateRecord("customerrefund", { 
    recordmode: "dynamic"
});

customerRefund.setFieldValue("customer", creditMemo.getFieldValue("entity"));
customerRefund.setFieldValue("paymentmethod", paymentMethod.id);
var account = ifxFindRecord.find("account", "number", "1099");
customerRefund.setFieldValue("account", account.id);
customerRefund.setFieldValue("trandate", nlapiDateToString(nlapiStringToDate(this.today())));
customerRefund.setFieldValue("total", creditMemo.getFieldValue("total"));
customerRefund.setFieldValue("memo", "Created from Credit Memo #" + creditMemoTransId);
customerRefund.setFieldValue("custbody_ifx_created_from", creditMemoId);

var credits = nlapiSearchRecord("creditmemo", null, new nlobjSearchFilter("createdfrom", null, "is", returnAuth.id), null);

nlapiLogExecution("debug", "line count", customerRefund.getLineItemCount("apply"));
for (var i = 1, len = customerRefund.getLineItemCount("apply"); i <= len; i++) {
    nlapiLogExecution("debug", "line item ", 
        "id: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "doc", i) +
        " apply: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "apply", i) +
        " due: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "due", i) +
        " amount: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "amount", i));
}
for (var iCredit = 0; iCredit < credits.length; iCredit++) {                    
    var creditId = credits[iCredit].getId();
    for (var i = 1, len = customerRefund.getLineItemCount("apply"); i <= len; i++) {
        nlapiLogExecution("debug", "line item doc", customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "doc", i)); 
        if (customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "doc", i) == creditId) {
            customerRefund.setLineItemValue("apply", "apply", i, "T");  // mark apply as true
            customerRefund.setLineItemValue("apply", "amount", i, customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "due", i));
            nlapiLogExecution("debug", "line apply"); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
for (var i = 1, len = customerRefund.getLineItemCount("apply"); i <= len; i++) {
    nlapiLogExecution("debug", "line item ", 
        "id: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "doc", i) +
        " apply: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "apply", i) +
        " due: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "due", i) +
        " amount: " + customerRefund.getLineItemValue("apply", "amount", i));
}

nlapiSubmitRecord(customerRefund, true);
```

But I end up with the error

```
USER_ERROR You must enter at least one line item for this transaction
```

The debugging output shows there is 3 sub list lines, 1 of which has been applied.

[image: One of the three sub list items was applied to the Customer Refund]

This code was working before the latest 2016 R1 release was updated on this account.

Where have I gone wrong or what can I try to get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

dynamic mode is interesting. 
I avoid it whenever possible but your line items need to be set up with:

```
customerRefund.selectLineItem('apply', i);
customerRefund.setCurrentLineItemValue('apply', 'apply', 'T', true, true);
...
customerRefund.commitLineItem('apply');
```

Comment: I don't know what the dynamic mode does, just something I saw somewhere and tried in desperation. I'm using this in a Workflow Action, so I'm thinking I don't have access to selectLineItem setCurrentLineItemValue and commitLineItem. Those are only available in the Client, right?

Comment: No. They are available server side too for dynamic mode records. Does setting the entity through initialization not work?  Then just skip the dynamic mode part